# how to loop through 2d array and make the result appear in table form in android

Tags: android, database, loops, format, cursor

HI below is the code which gets the four columns data from the curson and put in the 2d array. basically there are two issues one is that i get the last value as nullnullnullnull means all for columns are fetched as null.

the seconds is that i want to print the array in multitextline or if any other widget availabe so that i get four fields in a row. like
id rule_body rule_con boole
0  abc       def      1
0  a           f      0

```
    c.moveToFirst();
        int i=0;

                    while(c.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    String rb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rule_body"));
                    String cn = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rule_cons"));
                    String bl = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("boole"));
                    table[i][0] = id;
                    table[i][1] = rb;
                    table[i][2] = cn;
                    table[i][3] = bl;
                    ++i;
                }

            for(int a=0;a<count_row;a++)
                for(int b=0;b<count_col;b++) {

                    obj_ml.append(String.valueOf(table[a][b]));
                }
```

so far i am getting all the result in a single line. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for-loop as below

```
for (int a=0;a<count_row;a++)
{
     for(int b=0;b<count_col;b++) 
      {
          obj_ml.append(String.valueOf(table[a][b]));
      }
     // add to obj_ml new line character '\n'
     obj_ml.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, i cant give u any thing right now except a nice comment :) u r the boss

Comment: You welcome, you can always mark as a correct answer :)